# MS Access 2016: How to delete a macro?

Tags: macros, microsoft-access

I use Access of the Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 package. I played a little bit with the Creation of Macros. I safed a macro named "Makro1". Now I want to delete that Macro, because I don't want any garbage in the production version. How can I delete that Macro?

I tried it in the following way:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZrtv.png)

I clicked on Makro. Then the following Window appear:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3FoH.png)

In that window I can't delete Macros. I have only the option to copy them.

Answer (score 1):

You do that in the **Navigation pane**.

Select the object, press `Del`.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-the-navigation-pane-274dfc5a-281b-472b-94e2-ef931c5cc590